# git log custom format equivalent to git log --oneline?

Tags: git

I wanna to show ref name with custom log format when print history.

Currently the format is `%ad %h %s %an %am`

And I want to add the ref name behind `%ad`

I don't know how to print it, is there any one could help me?

For example:

`4a0fc56 (HEAD -> feature-ts, origin/feature-ts) fix(ts): remove type entry temporary`

The `(HEAD -> feature-ts, origin/feature-ts)` is what I wanted.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats): *`%d`: ref names, like the `--decorate` option of `git-log`*? Or perhaps *`%D`: ref names without the " (", ")" wrapping.*?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get the `ref name` and in `4a0fc56 (HEAD -> feature-ts, origin/feature-ts) fix(ts): remove type entry temporary` format, use:

```
git log --graph --format="%h %d %s"
```

According to [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) `%d` is for ref name, like the --decorate option of git-log.

To make it pretty, use `pretty format`

```
git log --graph --format="%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s"
```

This will print the commit hash in red, the ref in yellow and the subject in default.

Comment: Thank you very much, I use `git log --graph --decorate --date=format-local:'%m-%d %H:%M' --pretty=format:'%ad %C(cyan)%h%C(reset) %C(auto)%d %s %C(yellow)%an<%ae>%Creset%C(auto)' --all` finally.